# ColorBox JQuery Form Plugin Post To Same ColorBox

Tags: ajax, colorbox

I have been trying for two days to get ColorBox to return post results back to the same open box but it just will not do it.

I am using Jquery Form Plugin to Post from a ColorBox. It seems to work in IE 8, but not Safari or FireFox.

In IE 8 it returns the result from the post page "action" and returns the result in the same ColorBox but in FF and Safari it closes the box and sits on the load page (i.e. process1.php)?

1. I have a page say "process1.php" which loads the ColorBox onLoad (it does this no problem)

**Load Page ColorBox Code For process1.php:**

---

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j.fn.colorbox({
        href:"process2.php", 
        escKey: false, 
        overlayClose: false, 
        width: "60%", 
        height: 350, 
        title: "Process Secure Order", 
        open:true
    });
 });
```

---

- 1. Upon Page Load it will load the "process2.php" displaying a form for the user to submit data.

**This is my JQuery Form Plugin Code:**

---

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var options = { 
        beforeSubmit: showSpinner, 
        success: showResponse,
        //resetForm: true,
        timeout: 3000, 
        target: '#output1'
    };
    function showSpinner() { 
        $j('#sterms, #accept, #decline, #side-cart').hide();
        $j('#working').show().html('Please Wait');
        return true; 
    };
    function showResponse(){
        $j('#working').hide();
        $j('#result').show();
        return true; 
    };
    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $j('#secure_process01').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

---

It posts fine and then just tries to reload the same page with out the ColorBox opening on Load.

**It has me stumped why it works in IE and nothing else, any help would be appreciated.**

Using JQuery 1.5.2 (JQuery Form Plug In is not working with anything higher has permission issues)
Reference For JQuery Form Plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved.

It turned out that the Jquery Form Plugin did not like the 1.6.1 JQuery version so I did the code using Jquery Post and it worked in all browsers.

ColorBox plugin big rap, great and easy.